# Compactness- Euclidean metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Hi Could you help me to solve this question?

IF  $||.||$  be any norm on   $\mathbb{R}^m$  and let   $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m  : ||x||≤ 1 \}$ . Prove that   $B$  is compact. Hint: It suffices to show that   $B$  is closed and bounded with respect to the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Which definition of compactness are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The euclideian metric induces the norm $d_2(x,0)=||x||_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_m^2}$.

Now in a finite dimensional space $X$ all the norms are equivalent thus are equivalent with $||.||_2$ i.e: $\exists C_1,C_2>0 $ such that $C_1||x||_2 \leqslant||x|| \leqslant C_2||x||_2, \forall x \in X$.

Now $B$ is bounded with respect to the norm $||.||_2$  thus form the equivalence of norms  it is bounded with respect to $||.||$

Also let $x_n \in B$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

We have that $||x_n|| \leqslant 1$ and also we have that $||x_n|| \rightarrow ||x||$(the  norm is a continuous function).

Thus $||x|| \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow x \in B$.

We proved that $B$ is closed.

Comment: thank you Ramiz Karaeski

Comment: you are welcome